# Android: How to show only one class from website in webview in android

Tags: android, html, webview

```
  WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
  {
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
    {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return false;
    }
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
      {
       webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByClassName('storyTieUp');");
      }
  };
   webView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.browser ); 
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
   webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   webView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
   webView.loadUrl("http://stars.nhl.com/club/newsindex.htm");
```

This is my webViewClient code i just want to display only the div contents whose class name is 'storyTieUp', when i run this code it shows whole website contents, but i need only one div to show in webview, as i use Jsoup for that in some portions but here i don't want to use Jsoup because of some reasons, Is there any solution to only display one div by class name, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have any one of you know how to solve above listed problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, please remove `view.loadUrl(url);` from `shouldOverrideURLLoading`. It's not needed and causes performance issues. The URL load is already in progress; you don't need to start it again.

I don't think there's a simple way to delete all nodes other than `storyTieUp` in an HTML document. You could perhaps take the `innerHTML` of the node and then form that HTML into a new document to display.

Calling the JavaScript from `onPageFinished` may be non-deterministic. This callback is invoked when the resources of the page have been loaded from the network and not necessarily when they have been parsed or the DOM has been fully constructed. That means your JavaScript may fail.

The code you have at the moment would select the element, but then doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: thanks for replying, I understand what you want to say, as you say i just selecting the element, then how i use this selected element into my java to display only the contents

Comment: The only way I can think of is to have the JavaScript return the HTML content of the node to your java app and then load that HTML into your WebView, perhaps as a data URL (see WebView.loadData()). You can use document.getElementByClassName('storyTieUp').innerHTML to get the HTML content of the node. You may run into issues though if the HTML content relies on other resources in the document, like a stylesheet for example.